# Azure Kubernetes Services with Terraform load balancer shows "Internal Server Error"?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to setup Azure Kubernetes Services with Terraform with the 'Azure Voting'-app.

I'm using the code mentioned below, however I keep getting the error on the Load Balancer: "Internal Server Error". Any idea what is going wrong here?

Seems like the Load Balancer to Endpoint (POD) is configured correclt,y thus not sure what is missing here.

**main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "kubernetescluster"
  resource_group_name = "myResourceGroup"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config[0].host

  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "azurevote" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "azurevote-annotation"
    }

    labels = {
      mylabel = "azurevote-value"
    }

    name = "azurevote"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "terraform-example"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_pod.example.metadata.0.labels.app
    }
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_pod" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "terraform-example"
    labels = {
      app = "azure-vote-front"
    }
  }

  spec {
    container {
        image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1"
        name  = "example"
    }
  }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "prefix" {
    type = string
    default = "ab"
    description = "A prefix used for all resources in this example"
}
```

Comment: Is the **application** returning an internal server error, or the **load balancer**? Are you sure you've configured the application correctly and have all the appropriate preqreqs running in your cluster? That application requires Redis. Are you running it?

Comment: @Jay I'm sure I already asked this in another question you posted, but what do you type in when trying to access the app? Load balancer URL, Load Balancer + port number?

Comment: Load Balancer URL on port 80. I still needed to deploy the backend (only the frontend was there) and I had to configure the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your infrastructure setup is ok, the only thing is the application itself, you create only the front app, and you need to create the backend app to.

You can see the deployment examples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/master/azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml).

You also can see [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/0382ae322dfe5639b25a0e5ad94255119bc2ed0e/azure-vote/azure-vote/main.py#L41) the exception when you run the frontend without the backend.