# Terraform AKS load balancer forwarding pod issue: Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks

I've created the solution below with Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS) and Terraform. For some reason the Load Balancer gives me the error on the HTTP page: "**Internal Server Error**".

My current findings are:

- The Load Balancer is connected to the Front-end.
- The frontend pod is up and running
- The backend pod is already up and running

What is going wrong here?

The screenshots below will give you an overview how the setup looks in the Azure Portal. Secondly, I've also included the AKS/Terraform code to give you an idea how it looks like.

Pods
[image]

Service and Ingress
[image]

Infra.tf

```json
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "infra" {
  name                = "${var.resourcegroup}"
  location            = "${var.location}"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "infra" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-aks"
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resourcegroup}"
  dns_prefix          = "${var.prefix}-aks"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_DS2_v2"
  }
  
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.infra,
  ]
}
```

App.tf

```json
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-aks"
  resource_group_name = var.resourcegroup
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config[0].host

  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "azurevote" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "azurevote-annotation"
    }

    labels = {
      mylabel = "azurevote-value"
    }

    name = var.namespace
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "aks-azurevote-front" {
  metadata {
    name = "azure-vote-front"
    namespace = var.namespace
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_pod.aks-azurevote-back.metadata.0.labels.app
    }
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_namespace.azurevote,
  ]
}

resource "kubernetes_pod" "aks-azurevote-front" {
  metadata {
    name = "azure-vote-front"
    namespace = var.namespace
    labels = {
      app = "azure-vote-front"
    }
  }
  spec {
    container {
      image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1"
      name  = "front"
      env {
        name  = "ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD"
        value = "yes"
      }
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_namespace.azurevote,
  ]
}

resource "kubernetes_pod" "aks-azurevote-back" {
  metadata {
    name      = "azure-vote-back"
    namespace = var.namespace
    labels = {
      app = "azure-vote-back"
    }
  }
  spec {
    container {
      image = "mcr.microsoft.com/oss/bitnami/redis:6.0.8"
      name  = "back"
      env {
        name  = "ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD"
        value = "yes"
      }
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_namespace.azurevote,
  ]
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "aks-azurevote-back" {
  metadata {
    name      = "azure-vote-back"
    namespace = var.namespace
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_pod.aks-azurevote-back.metadata.0.labels.app
    }
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = 6379
      target_port = 6379
    }

    type = "ClusterIP"
  }
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_namespace.azurevote,
  ]
}
```

Comment: a 500 errors sounds like the traffic reaches your pod alright, but your pod has issues serving the request. check your pod's logs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Kubernetes Services with Terraform load balancer shows "Internal Server Error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71330392/azure-kubernetes-services-with-terraform-load-balancer-shows-internal-server-er)

Comment: You are using the same selector label for frontend and backend: `app = kubernetes_pod.aks-azurevote-back.metadata.0.labels.app`. Should those be different? In other words, should frontend app have a different label compared to the backend app?